black3 dependency is stopping my cargo build not sure what this errors reason is for
failed to select a version for `blake3` which could resolve this conflict
jasonwilliams@Jasons-MacBook-Pro solana-arbitrage-bot % cargo tree -e features | grep blake3
    Updating git repository `https://github.com/solana-labs/solana`
    Updating crates.io index
error: failed to select a version for `blake3`.
    ... required by package `solana-arbitrage-bot v0.1.0 (/Users/jasonwilliams/Project/solana-arbitrage-bot)`
versions that meet the requirements `^1.5.4` are: 1.5.4

the package `solana-arbitrage-bot` depends on `blake3`, with features: `digest` but `blake3` does not have these features.
 It has an optional dependency with that name, but that dependency uses the "dep:" syntax in the features table, so it does not have an implicit feature with that name.

failed to select a version for `blake3` which could resolve this conflict


The blake3 crate was upgraded in this pull request to remove the "digest" feature: https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/pull/2959
This feature was removed in the blake3 crate, which is why you're seeing an error.
You have two options to resolve the issue:

Use the v2.1 Solana crates
Pin blake3 with =1.5.1 in your Cargo.toml


Probably a version issue with the solana-program crate
Try pinning the crate on a particular Solana version
e.g
solana-program = "=2.0.2"

